# How to wait with Fragment Transaction until Fragment View is created

Tags: android, animation, transactions, fragment

Is there any way to wait with the animation of a Fragment Transaction until the view of the new Fragment is completely created?

Any help is much appreciated.

Creating the view in my case takes some time because constraints are being set and text is being formated with SpannableStringBuilder. Therefore the animation is being skipped in most cases because there is too much work on the main thread.

```
// Kotlin

val newFragment = MyFragment()
val backStackName = "myfragment"

val fragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager
val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right)
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.MyFragmentLayout, newFragment)
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStackName)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Instead of using custom animation like this

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right)
```

I used enterTransition

```
val enterTransition = Slide(Gravity.RIGHT)
enterTransition.addTarget(R.id.MyFragmentLayout)
newFragment.enterTransition = enterTransition
```

Now the animation will not start until the view is created.